# Function that, when composed with itself, is equivalent to summing certain arguments

Tags: terminology, function-and-relation-composition

Let's say I have a function that takes some real argument $t$ and some other argument ${\bf x}_0 \in D$, that returns ${\bf x}_1 \in D$ (for some domain D).

${\bf x}_1 = f({\bf x_0}, t)$

I'm interested in functions of this form that have the property where composing them with themselves is equivalent to evaluating them once with the sum of the $t$ arguments, so we get this identity:

$f\left( f( {\bf x_0}, t_1), t_2 \right) = f( {\bf x_0}, t_1 + t_2)$

**But I don't know if this property has a standard name or way of describing it.**

---

tl;dr is above; below, I show some examples and motivate why I'm looking for this property.

Here are two functions with this property:

$\require{cancel}\begin{align}
g(a, t) &= a + ct\\
g(g(a, t_1), t_2) &= (a + ct_1) + ct_2\\
&=a + c(t_1 + t_2)\\
&= g(a, t_1 + t_2)\\
\\
h(a, t) &= a + (b - a)(1 - d^t)\\
h(h(a, t_1), t_2)&= \left[a + (b - a)(1 - d^{t_1})\right] + \left(b - \left[a + (b - a)(1 - d^{t_1})\right]\right)(1 - d^{t_2})\\
&=a + (b-a)(1 - d^{t_1}) + (b-a)(1-d^{t_2}) - (b-a)(1-d^{t_1})(1 - d^{t_2})\\
&= a + (b-a)(1 \cancel{- d^{t_1}} \cancel{+ 1} \cancel{- d^{t_2}} \cancel{- 1} \cancel{+ d^{t_1}} \cancel{+ d^{t_2}} + d^{t_1 + t_2})\\
&= a + (b - a)(1 - d^{t_1 + t_2})\\
&= h(a, t_1 + t_2)
\end{align}$

I'm coming at this from game development, where we often want functions with this property to step some initial game state ${\bf x}_0$ forward in time by a duration of time $t \ge 0$. In that application:

- The single evaluation form $f({\bf x_0}, t_1 + t_2)$ corresponds to the game running at a low framerate, so we try to simulate a big jump forward in time all at once.
- The composed form $f\left( f( {\bf x_0}, t_1), t_2 \right)$ corresponds to the game running at a high framerate, so we step the simulation forward in two consecutive frames over the same real-time interval, taking smaller sub-steps.

We'd like to get the same answer, regardless of how many steps we took along the way. This property of equivalence between the two forms gives us "framerate independence" (or *approximately* so, since [in practice we have rounding errors and other complications](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/132835/39518) that aren't relevant here), helping the game achieve a consistent look and feel on different hardware or under different load conditions. That makes this property desirable in our game simulation math, but I don't know the proper terms to discuss it mathematically, or if there's a neater/more standardized way to formalize it than the way I've presented it above.

**Is there a standard name for this property**, or functions with this property? Or a neater way to show that a function of a particular form must have this property than the algebra I used above?

Comment: I think that the notion of "flow" is what you are looking for; see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flow_(mathematics)#Formal_definition

Comment: That looks right to me, thank you! I'd upvote/accept that as an answer.